# How to avoid delay in synchronous web service call in Spotify application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spotify

Friends,

For my spotify application i am calling webservices for 50 songs.

```
var search = new models.Search("Rock");
search.localResults = models.LOCALSEARCHRESULTS.APPEND;
search.pageSize=50;
```

It will fetch songs of Rock category.
So for each song i am calling 3 webservices & getting responce.
I have made web service call synchronous because i am storing response data in array
I am using $ajax call from jquery.

```
type: 'GET',
url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=artistname&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json',
dataType: 'json',
timeout: 1000,
```

Even after mentioning timeout variable it crashes into infinite waiting.
Can somebody tell me how to improve this web service call?

For my application i am keeping in mind that my application initially will take time to load but once loaded it will be fast to ececute.
I am using synchronous call here because i want to store values into array at appropriate index which in case of asynchrous call doesnt workout.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to ever avoid synchronous calls. Synchronous calls are blocking, which is very bad for user experience... especially if you do 3*50 requests !

You have always a way to do it asynchronously. For example you can use javascripts closures to store tab index in your callback function:

```
var tab = [];
for (var i=0 ; i < N ; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=artistname&api_key=b25b959554ed76058ac220b7b2e0a026&format=json',
    dataType: 'json',
    timeout: 1000,
    success: (function(i){return function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
      tab[i] = data;
    }})(i)
  });
}
```

Besides that, I find that 3 calls * 50 songs is *a lot* of AJAX calls and your page may load very slowly... Maybe can you factorize your calls ?